# Find lost photos that show in screen saver

Tags: macos, photos, screensaver, library

Wonderful older photos that aren't in my library show up on my screen saver. I would love to be able to get to them! I currently use 10.9.3, but this has been happening for a long time.

Answer (score 1):

Photos in the screen saver come from the source that is selected in **System Preferences** → **Desktop & Screen Saver**. This means that your missing photos will be in whatever source has been selected there.

[image]